# using d3 for directed graph visualization

Tags: d3.js

I want to use d3 force-directed layout for visualizing my graph. However, I want to show edge direction since it is a directed graph. Is it possible to show this using d3?

Comment: can you explain a bit how or link me to a sample? I can't find anything by searching.

Comment: I have made forced-directed layout working, but it's for undirected graph thus doesnot show link edge directions

Comment: See e.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292).